# How to break $.each

Tags: jquery, webmethod

i am using $.each of jquery like this

```
$.each($('.FormContainer div.MainDiv'), function () {
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: pageUrl + '/SaveFormResponse',
      data: jsonText,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
      if (isNaN(response.d) == false) {
          //continue executing $.each further
      }
      else {
          alert(response.d);
          //stop executing $.each further in case of error 
      }
      },
      failure: function (response) {
           alert(response.d);
      }

    });

});
```

now problem is that in case of error i want $.each to stop executing further but it's not stopping till it will not traverse through all the div's

i also tried maintaining a variable and check it's value on every iteration and set it's value on error but still not working

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so breaking the loop in the callback won't do you any good, as the loop has long since completed.

Comment: Use promises and deffered objects. Are you sure there is a `failure` handler?

Comment: why are you iterating over a set of divs but not retrieving any information from them?

Comment: i am doing a lot of work there but not posted here because it is so much of code

Comment: But essentially you make a request based on the content of each div, and want to abort further requests if one gives an invalid response?

Comment: `isNaN` will always return false for data from a json object - the json specification does not define a representation for NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$.ajax` gives you a result, `$.each` has finished already. Note that the first "a" in ajax stands for asynchronous. What you can do is creating a recursive function (you didn't use anything specific from each element, but I assume you do so I used `$elem`):

```
var $elems = $('.FormContainer div.MainDiv');

(function fetch(i) {
    if(i >= $elems.length) return;  // no elems left

    var $elem = $elems.eq(i);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: pageUrl + '/SaveFormResponse',
      data: jsonText,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        if (!isNaN(response.d)) {
          fetch(i + 1);  // next one
        } else {
          alert(response.d);  // just don't call fetch again
        }
      },
      failure: function (response) {
         alert(response.d);
      }
    });
})(0);  // start with first elem
```

Answer (score 0):

Have'nt tested it, but I'm guessing something like this will do it without recursion or synchronous behavior:

```
var XHRarray = [];

$.each($('.FormContainer div.MainDiv'), function() {
    var XHR = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + '/SaveFormResponse',
        data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (isInteger(response.d)) {
            //continue executing $.each further
        }else{
            stopAll(); //stop all pending ajax requests
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        stopAll(); //stop all pending ajax requests
    });
    XHRarray.push(XHR);
});

function stopAll() {
    $.each(XHRarray, function(i,e) {
        e.abort();
    }
}​

function isInteger(s){ //checks string for numbers only
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (((c < "0") || (c > "9"))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To break $.each(), you need to return false

```
$(function() {
    var temp = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    $.each(temp, function(k, v) {
        $('body').append(v);
        if (v == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

​Output:

```
0123
```

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

But, if you want to work with asynchronous $.ajax() call like that, you will need to decide wether continue with next item or stop, inside callback function.

```
var currentItem = 0, itemSet = $('.FormContainer div.MainDiv');
function workOnItem(itemNum) {
      if (itemSet[itemNum] != undefined) {
      var item = itemSet[itemNum];
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + '/SaveFormResponse',
            data: jsonText,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
            if (isNaN(response.d) == false) {
                  //continue executing $.each further
                  currentItem++;
                  workOnItem(currentItem);
            }
            else {
                alert(response.d);
                //stop executing $.each further in case of error 
            }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                 alert(response.d);
            }
        });
      }
}
workOnItem(0);
```

Comment: @rahul what you were trying? Remeber, you need to `return false` in `$.each()` context, not inside `$.ajax()`

Comment: How do you expect this to work with an asynchronous method ??

Comment: @adeneo You just read the title of question. This IS correct answer. If the guy will improve his question, I will improve my answer.